# How to make URL on a PIC in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, image, url, link-to

I'm new to RoR so bear with me.

I have this forthcoming website open in Production Mode here:

**http://88.112.168.70/**

I have there 2 FB logo pics at the end of every sub-page (the GREEN area) and I honestly have no idea on how to insert URL LINKS on those logos.

The FB logos and the whole ending section currently comes from a LAYOUT file, of whichs' code is below:

```
  <tr>
<td class="otsikko-ala">

    <p class="small">

    <%=image_tag("facebook_logo-green.png", alt: "Tommi Tiihonen", :class=> "fb", :align=> "right")%>
    <%=image_tag("facebook_logo.png", alt: "Tommi Tiihonen", :class=> "fb", :align=> "right")%>

        <strong>Web-Studio</strong>
    <br>
        The World at Your Fingertips
    </p>

</td>
```

So if I would like to have an URL on both images to, say, URL: http://www.com, then how would I do that? I ALSO don't want any borders on the URLed FB logos. BUT I do want to have a Title Tag and an Alt Tag on those.

AND:::: I want to have the TARGET frame value as "_new".

Please if it isn't too much asked, could you put the whole tag here - not only the explanation.

Thanks in advance!

-Tommi

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a link out of an image, just do this:

```
<%= link_to 'http://www.com', target: "_blank", alt: "my alt here", title: "my title here" do
  <%= image_tag 'facebook_logo.png' %>

<% end %>
```